# What is the authorization for any technical central action in Ethereum system?

Tags: blockchain, security

When, after fully reviewing, pull requests management and a detailed discussions on github and so on, it arrives the moment in which someone must take into his hands the technical intervention on the code and/or on the blockchain or whatever... what is the mechanism used to authorize technical operators to implement the deiberated changes?

What is the mechanism that prevent the person(s) who act on the overall system to, let’s say as example, add 100 ether on some accounts or to move the balance of tokens or whatever?

In other word: how the community controls the technical administrators of the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, you're asking about how changes are enacted, once the geth/parity/etc. repositories are updated for a fork, correct?

If that's what you're asking, then it's the node operators. Mining pools, exchanges, users, services, etc. are all free to upgrade or not upgrade their nodes whenever they want. When there is a non-contentious, planned hardfork, upgrade support is usually above 90% when the hardfork activates.

The upgraded clients are all open source, so they can be verified that they don't do anything malicious. Furthermore, in order to avoid clients forking, all the clients would have to do the same malicious change (e.g. giving a certain address 100 eth) at the same time. That means it would have to be in a planned hardfork, which are heavily scrutinized before activation.

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that. So the check is “a-priori” because everyone, before to upgrade, can check the open-source code. Isn’t it? Thank you.

Comment: Exactly. Of course not everyone and their mom is expected to check the source, but enough people check it (and test between the clients for forks) that it's highly unlikely that all of the clients get the same malicious code through without someone noticing.